# Programming language without integer type

Tags: language-design

What would be shortcomings of a language without integer type (only float)? Which of them will be very serious or unsolvable? Suppose compiler is sufficiently smart to print rounded number when it knows, that this number is really integer. Was such idea discussed in scientific papers or implemented in some language (I cannot find neither).

Comment: Lua also doesn't have integer type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript is such a language:  all numbers are double-precision (64-bit) floating point.  There are a number of unfortunate consequences of this design choice, but clearly the result can be made to work...

Note that double-precision floating point can precisely represent integers of up to 53 bits.  So, it can be more practical than you might think to use it as an integer-substitute.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem in question is in two points, which are:

The "float" data require more processor, while data "integer" less relative to "float"; Therefore depending on the size of the program can occur overload.

The other point would be the main memory space used, following the same as the processor where the data "float" require more space than the data "integer".

I hope to have contributed to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

There's relatively new proposal for decimal floating point number http://dec64.com/ . It would be really interesting to see a language supporting it natively.

As for shortcomings of only using floats, nothing which would be a real problem comes to mind. Some operations would be strange, as it is case in JavaScript and things like bit twiddling.